# Please help me with this code self.opener.document.getElementById

Tags: javascript

i'm trying to get automatic fill in table cell each row , with have array id

I do this code:

```
        function insert_datarow(id,name,price){
            self.opener.document.getElementById('productCode_1').value=id;
        self.opener.document.getElementById('productName_1').value=name;
            self.opener.document.getElementById('price_1').value=price;
            window.close();
        }


<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="invoiceItem"> 
        <tr>
          <th width="2%"><input id="checkAll" class="formcontrol" type="checkbox"></th>
          <th width="15%">Item No</th>
          <th width="38%">Item Name</th>
          <th width="15%">Quantity</th>
          <th width="15%">Price</th>                
          <th width="15%">Total</th>
        </tr>             
        <tr>
          <td><input class="itemRow" type="checkbox"></td>
          <td><span class="input-group"><input type="text" name="productCode[]" id="productCode_1" class="form-control input-sm" autocomplete="off"><span class="input-group-btn">
          <a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick='open_win2()'><button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" type="button">Go!</button></a>
          </span></span></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="productName[]" id="productName_1" class="form-control input-sm" autocomplete="off"></td>      
          <td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_1" class="form-control input-sm quantity" autocomplete="off"></td>
          <td><input type="number" name="price[]" id="price_1" class="form-control input-sm" autocomplete="off"></td>
          <td><input type="number" name="total[]" id="total_1" class="form-control input-sm total" autocomplete="off" readonly=""></td>
        </tr>           
      </table>


var count = $(".itemRow").length;
$(document).on('click', '#addRows', function() { 
    count++;
    var htmlRows = '';
    htmlRows += '<tr>';
    htmlRows += '<td><input class="itemRow" type="checkbox"></td>';          
    htmlRows += '<td><span class="input-group"><input type="text" name="productCode[]" id="productCode_'+count+'" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"><span class="input-group-btn"><a href=\'javascript:void(0)\' onClick=\'open_win2()\'><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button></a></span></span></td>';          
    htmlRows += '<td><input type="text" name="productName[]" id="productName_'+count+'" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></td>'; 
    htmlRows += '<td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_'+count+'" class="form-control quantity" autocomplete="off"></td>';        
    htmlRows += '<td><input type="number" name="price[]" id="price_'+count+'" class="form-control " autocomplete="off"></td>';       
    htmlRows += '<td><input type="number" name="total[]" id="total_'+count+'" class="form-control total" autocomplete="off" readonly=""></td>';          
    htmlRows += '</tr>';
    $('#invoiceItem').append(htmlRows);
});
```

in ther first row when i click go is good to right place right cell, but when i add row and click go in second row , they fill in the first row , why not fill in the second or the same row.

Comment: Removed the unrelated tag `php` for you

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using an HTML element id "addRows" as a selector for onClick handler in js code but no reference for that id in HTML markup at all.
To fix behaviour you should replace this HTML:

```
<a href='javascript:void(0)' onClick='open_win2()'>
```

With a code something like this:

```
<a href='#' id='addRows'>
```

and the same for dynamic/quoted HTML you have:

```
htmlRows += '<td><span class="input-group"><input type="text" name="productCode[]" id="productCode_'+count+'" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"><span class="input-group-btn"><a href=\'javascript:void(0)\' onClick=\'open_win2()\'><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button></a></span></span></td>';
```

with something like this:

```
htmlRows += '<td><span class="input-group"><input type="text" name="productCode[]" id="productCode_'+count+'" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"><span class="input-group-btn"><a href=\'#\' id=\'addRows\'><button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Go!</button></a></span></span></td>';
```

But in this case you'll have several buttons with the same id which will work but not a good idea.
Maybe better to use a single event handler for a class selector like '.addNewRowBtn' and then just add this class to existed and generated buttons:

```
<a href='#' class='addNewRowBtn'>
```